# Return list of triplicates

Tags: bash, sorting, unique

To find duplicates you can use

```
sort | uniq -d
```

but is there a quick way to find triplicates?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use:

```
sort | uniq -c | awk '$1 == 3'
```

uniq -c gives you a count of occurences in the first column.  The awk line filters all lines with has 3 in the first column.

If you want all items occuring 3 or more times write `$1 >= 3`

You can also pick out just the items names with (if they are just one column with no spaces) with:

```
sort | uniq -c | awk '$1 >= 3 {print $2}'
```

Ans so on ...

Comment: Or more likely `$1 >= 3`, along with a `cut` or something to trim off the first field.

Comment: Depending on how "triplicates" is defined ... but yes if its meant 3 or more then you could use this.

Comment: `uniq -d` prints repeated lines, i.e. count >= 2, so by analogy I figured the OP wanted >=3.